# Python Gae Ajax, How to implement notification?

Tags: python, ajax, google-app-engine

I have this app that wants to implement a notification system that exactly like Stack Overflow's. When someone answer or reply to a question or a thread. I want the original user of the thread be able to get notified at the top bar of the site.  I've seen google channel api which is able to do that. But it is too expensive to do it if we use it for notification.  I've read about Node.js web sockets as well. But it doesn't look simple enough.  Anyone know where can I find a simple way to do it? Maybe just an Ajax call?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com/).

Even though you could you your job with the Channel API, it is a bit harder to implement since it supports only one on one channels, and if you want to sent one message to multiple clients, you will have to send multiple messages. With PubNub you can simply subscribe to a channel and no matter how many subscribers you have, they will all get the message.

They have examples in many different languages and Google App Engine is included, so take a look at the [PubNub Dev Center](http://www.pubnub.com/devcenter) for more.